# Analogy to Four Squares Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a multivariate and univariate polynomial analogy to Lagrange's sum of four squares?

Comment: Perhaps you should be more specific, e.g., about the coefficient ring. Anyway, over $\Bbb R$, any nonnegative polynomial $f$ can be written as the sum of the squares of just two polynomials.

Comment: @Travis that is interesting I was thinking of integers. How is what you state true?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823627/prove-that-p-in-mathbbrx-can-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-squares-of-polin

Comment: I do not know the corresponding answer for integer-coefficient polynomials.

Comment: Consider Waring's problem