# Is posible to write a polinomy in R like a square of "something" if it is all time positive for all values?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is it possible to write a  polinomy in R like a square of "something" if and only if that polinomy(in n variables, and grade m, with n and m naturals, ) is all time positive for all values? if it is possible consider another problem:
i, is there a method to write all positive polinomy in R like a square of something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ can be represented as a sum of squares of polinomials from $\mathbb{R}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823627/prove-that-p-in-mathbbrx-can-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-squares-of-polin)

Comment: By *polinomy* do you mean *[polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial)*? I think we usually call it *degree* of a polynomial rather than *grade*.

Comment: I am not particularly happy with self-invented jargon such as "polinomy" and "all time positive", but maybe that is just me?

Comment: @HansHüttel. It appears to be a translation difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can write $p(x)$ as the square of $\sqrt{p(x)}$.

More interestingly,
you can write a real polynomial in one variable
that is always non-negative as a finite sum of squares of real polynomials.

You can also write a real polynomial in two or more variables which
is always nonnegative for real arguments, as a finite sum of squares
of rational functions with real coefficients, but not necessarily the
sum of squares of real polynomials.