# Brezis' exercise 6.22.4: prove that $Q(T)$ is bijective

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E$ be a real Banach space, and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. Given a polynomial $Q(t)=\sum_{k=0}^p a_k t^k$ with $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$, let $Q(T)=\sum_{k=0}^p a_k T^k$.
>
> 1. Prove that $Q(E V(T)) \subset E V(Q(T))$.
> 2. Prove that $Q(\sigma(T)) \subset \sigma(Q(T))$.
> 3. Construct an example in $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ for which the above inclusions are strict.
>
> In what follows we assume that $E$ is a Hilbert space (identified with its dual space $H^*$) and that $T^* = T$.
>
> 4. Assume here that the polynomial $Q$ has no real root, i.e., $Q(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $Q(T)$ is bijective.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (4). Could you please have a check on it?

---

WLOG, we assume $Q (t) >0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823627/prove-that-p-in-mathbbrx-can-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-squares-of-polyn) there are polynomials $Q_1, \ldots, Q_m$ and a constant $\alpha>0$ such that $Q(t) = \sum_{k=1}^m Q_k^2(t) + \alpha$. We have $(Q_k(T))^* = Q_k(T^*)$, so $Q_k (T)$ is self-adjoint for $k=1, \ldots,m$. Let $P(t) := \sum_{k=1}^m Q_k^2(t)$.

First, we prove that $P(T)$ is positive, i.e., $\langle P(T)u, u \rangle \ge 0$ for all $u \in H$. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle P(T)u, u \rangle &= \sum_{k=1}^m \langle Q_k^2 u, u \rangle \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m \langle Q_k u, Q_k u \rangle \text{ because } Q_k \text{ is self-adjoint}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m  |Q_ku|^2 \ge 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Second, we verify that $P(T)+\alpha I$ is injective. Let $u\in H$ such $(P(T)+\alpha I)u=0$. Then $P(T)u = -\alpha u$. Then $u=0$ because
$$
0 \le \langle P(T)u, u \rangle = -\alpha \langle u, u \rangle = -\alpha|u|^2.
$$

Finally, we prove that $P(T)+\alpha I$ is surjective. It's clear that $P(T)$ and thus $P(T)+\alpha I$ are self-adjoint. For $u\in H$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
|(P(T)+\alpha I)u|^2 &= |P(T)u|^2 +2\alpha \langle P(T)u, u \rangle + \alpha^2|u|^2 \\
&\ge \alpha^2|u|^2 + 2\alpha \langle P(T)u, u \rangle \\
&\ge \alpha^2|u|^2 \text{ because } P(T) \text{ is positive}.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows from below *Theorem 2.21.* in the same book, i.e.,

> Let $E, F$ be real Banach spaces. For a linear map $T$, we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range. Let $A: D(A) \subset E \to F$ be an unbounded linear operator that is densely defined and has a closed graph.
>
> **Theorem 2.20.** The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (a) $A$ is surjective, i.e., $R(A)=F$,
> - (b) there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
>   |v| \leq C |A^* v| \quad \forall v \in D (A^*),
>   $$
> - (c) $N (A^*) = \{0\}$ and $R(A^*)$ is closed.
>
> **Theorem 2.21.** The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (a) $A^*$ is surjective, i.e., $R(A^*)=E^*$,
> - (b) there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
>   |u| \leq C |A u| \quad \forall u \in D (A),
>   $$
> - (c) $N (A) = \{0\}$ and $R(A)$ is closed.